# how to implement nested comments 2 levels deep in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am trying to implement a commenting system on my website that is only two levels deep for example you will have the main comment and replies to that comment but it does not go any further:

```
main comment 1
  (sub_comment1)
  (sub_comment2)

main comment 2
  (sub_comment1)
  (sub_comment2)
  (sub_comment2)
```

etc...

Make sense?

I am creating the site in codeigniter but i think a basic php solution will do.

each row in my database table has an id and a parent_id, if the parent id is 0 then its a main comment and if its a sub-comment it will have the id of its parent comment in parent_id.

how to I feed a two dimensional array with the parent and child comments in the right order.

My current code is like so: The controller:

```
 function status_comments($id){

    $this->load->model('status_model');//load the status model
    $this->load->model('comment_model');//load the comment model

    $status = $this->status_model->get_entry_and_category($id); 
    $comments = $this->comment_model->get_comments($id);   

    if($status !== false) {

        if($comments !== false) {

            foreach($comments as $comment){

                  if($comment->reply_id == 0){

                    $comment =   

                  }
            }


            $content_data['comments'] = $comments; 

        }        

        $content_data['status'] = $status; 
        $data['content'] = $this->load->view('status_view', $content_data, TRUE);
        $data['title'] = $status->title.' - High Value Status'; 
        $data['page_title'] = $status->title;//The page H1 tag
        $this->load->view('home', $data);   

    }
    else 
    { 
        $this->session->set_flashdata('invalid', '<p class="rejectionalert"><span>The status you tried to view does not exist.</span></p>');
        redirect('home'); 
    }

}
```

The model function:

```
//Gets comments associated with an individual status   
function get_comments($status_id, $offset=null, $limit=null)
{
    $this->db->select('id, comment, nickname, created, reply_id');
    $this->db->from('comments');
    $this->db->where('active', 1);
    $this->db->where('status_id', $status_id);

    $query = $this->db->get(); 

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

        return $query->result();      
    }

    return false;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works but its using more than one query, the model:

```
 function get_comments($status_id, $limit=NULL, $offset=NULL)
 {
    $this->db->where(array('status_id' => $status_id, 'reply_id' => 0));
    $query = $this->db->get('comments', $limit, $offset);

    $parents = $query->result_array();
    $comments = array(); 

    foreach($parents as $key => $comment)
    {
        array_push($comments, $comment);

        $this->db->order_by('created', 'ASC');
        $this->db->where(array('status_id' => $status_id, 'reply_id' => $comment['id']));

        $comments = array_merge($comments, $this->db->get('comments')->result_array());
    }

    return $comments;   

}
```

I thought it would be more efficent to make one query of all comments, index them into an array by their id, and iterate over them again to find their children. I still dont know how to implement that?